# The Clock is not getting scaled properly

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

For some reason, the clock is not getting positioned properly. I have no idea why. I have tried to change the values of the numbers but this is the best I got it too. I really hope someone could help me out with this. I am trying to make it so that the hands of the clock don't stick out too much too.

Comment: post your `ClockView` class

Comment: Ok. I did that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop where you draw the dashed outline:

```dart
var outerCircleRadius = radius;
var innerCircleRadius = radius - 14;
for (double i = 0; i < 360; i += 12) {
  var x1 = centerX + outerCircleRadius * cos(i * pi / 180);
  var y1 = centerX + outerCircleRadius * sin(i * pi / 180);

  var x2 = centerX + innerCircleRadius * cos(i * pi / 180);
  var y2 = centerX + innerCircleRadius * sin(i * pi / 180);
  canvas.drawLine(Offset(x1, y1), Offset(x2, y2), dashBrush);
}
```

In the assignment for `y1` and `y2`, `centerX` should be `centerY`.

EDIT: Looking at the rest of the code, there are a lot of places where `centerX` should be `centerY`. Always double-check code that you copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was so confused but now it is fixed .

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I also have another question about the same code. Could you please help me with it? Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361096/sign-not-showing-up-for-some-reason-there-is-a-sign-idk-why. Thanks.